# Python - attribute specific values with imbricated loops

Tags: python, for-loop, numpy, while-loop, break

I have some problems to store values with imbricated loops...
It s an example which is close of my case.
In order to limit the size of the code, i have added "a" as a random values.

For each "image", i have to calculate dX and if i can reach my criterion, i put a specific value (100) and i break the loop to go next image! If i cant converge before my iteration maximum value, i force an another value (1) and i break too loops for next image case.

```
import numpy 

res = zeros((len(range(0,5,1)),2)) #array of results

dX = 10. #my important value which allow stop loop for one "image"
n = 0 #number of iteration
itmax = 5. #my iteration max value 


#I have to achieve calculations on a great number of cases (image - and i want to store results of each case in "res array")

for image in range(0,5,1):

  a = randint(0,9) #for this example, i added a random value to treat the problem

  while abs(dX) > 5.: 

    dX = a - n

    if abs(dX) < 5.:
      res[image,0] = 100.
      res[image,1] = 100.

    elif n==itmax: 
      res[image,0] = 1.
      res[image,1] = 1.
      break

    n = n+1

res
```

But currently i got always zeros arrays as it doesnt happen...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still wonder what you are trying to do but this code seems already more reasonable and could work as you want:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import numpy as np
import pylab

nb_images = 5

# array of results
results = np.zeros([nb_images, 2])

# my iteration max value
itmax = 5.

# I have to achieve calculations on a great number of cases (image -
# and I want to store results of each case in "res array")
for image in range(nb_images):
    # my important value which allow stop loop for one "image"
    dX = 10.
    # for this example, I added a random value to treat the problem
    a = pylab.randint(0, 9)

    print('dX:', dX, '(entering the while loop...)')
    n = 0
    while dX > 5:
        dX = a - n
        if dX < 5:
            results[image, :] = 100.
        elif n == itmax:
            results[image, :] = 1.
            break
        n += 1
        print('dX:', dX)

print(results)
```

Apart from modifications to respect the [pep 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) (And by the way, you should use a good editor that helps you by pointing out simple errors and style problems. A good editor for beginners is for example [spyder](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/spyder)), I moved `dX = 10` and `n = 0` inside the for loop and remove the `abs` in the condition on `dX`. I hope it's going to help you to write better Python code.

Comment: thanks for help! ;) but i m asking why i continue to have some values equal to zero...? for me u can have only 1 or 100 as value, it s what i expect

Comment: I think i have to specify <=,  it s ok ;)